# Why does excel file opens when opening connection using ADO?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, ado

1. I've used ADO before connecting and getting data from Excel files in my ***Local Drive***.
    
   It is *not opening the file* which is what I expect.
2. Now I'm trying to do the same but this time on Excel files located in a ***Network Drive***.
   To my surprise, *it opens the file*, though still get the data I need.

Is this the way it should be? Or am I missing something?

**Code I use:**

```
Sub conscious()
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rec As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim dataSource As String

    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rec = New ADODB.Recordset
    dataSource = "R:\Folder\excelfile.xlsb"

    Dim sconnect As String
    sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & dataSource & ";HDR=Yes;"
    con.Open sconnect: DoEvents 
    Dim sqlstr As String
    sqlstr = "SELECT [H1], [H2], [H3], [H4], [H5], [H6], " & _
            "[H7], [H8], [H9], [H10]" & _
            "FROM [Sheetname$] " & _
            "WHERE H8 IN ('citeria1','criteria2') " & _
            "AND H9 < 29 " & _
            "AND H10 = 1 " & _
            "ORDER By H7;"

    rec.Open sqlstr, con, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly: DoEvents

    With Sheet1
        Dim lrow As Long
        lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If lrow > 1 Then .Range("A2:J" & lrow).ClearContents
        .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rec
    End With

    rec.Close: con.Close
    Set rec = Nothing: Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use the ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider? Or don't use `adLockReadOnly`?

Comment: @Rory I've used that, actually that is my first code. I've also tried your suggestion removing the `adLockReadOnly` and it is still opening it.

Comment: @mehow I see the file open. I mean it is there in a readonly state. Also I saw the status of opening it.

Comment: @L42 um.. mine remains closed :/ strange

Comment: @mehow Yeah, I was surprised as well. Does it have something to do with how our network was set up? or maybe restriction on folders?

Comment: @L42 probably not a question I can answer but one suggestion would be to try to pull data of a closed workbook on a network drive with ExecuteExcel4Macro and see if that also opens the file

Comment: @mehow Yeah, I just thought that you might be aware of some considerations. But anyway, I tried your suggestion using ExecuteExcel4Macro and it does not open the file. I used the same file.

Comment: I can't replicate what you're describing. Which version of Excel and which ADO library?

Comment: @Rory XL2010, 6.1 Library

Comment: Tested with the same, still don't see the file open.

Comment: @Rory Really appreciate you guys helping. I myself can't believe it is opening the file. I'll do some digging with what might be causing this and hopefully I can get back to you guys and explain what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging, I finally found out what's the reason behind this oddity.
I checked with our ***Network Admin*** to check on the file and it is in an infinite open state.
Somebody used it and somehow failed to close it properly.
I tried to open it manually and a message that 'Another User' is currently using the file pops-up.

I got the Admin to reset the status and hola!
I can now connect and get data without opening the file.

To those who've looked into these, I appreciate it. But for my (and for those who'll read this in the future) peace of mind, can you do the same testing to validate if it does behave as such?
Open the target file using another machine.
 Then using another, run above code and see if it replicates what I've described.
 If it does, then we're all settled.

**Edit1:** You'll have to use this line instead for above code to work.

```
sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & dataSource & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"";"
```

Comment: If somebody else validated that above is true, I'll mark my own answer.

Comment: Yes, it is happening to me now. The problem is that I can't work around it. The file is really open on other machine and then I can't query data from it using ADO. Bigger problem: my VBA can't pull data from that file, it jus give me an error saying the the object could't be found.